# Vitest running, but not not updating results of tests after modification of files

Tags: vite, vitest

I'm running tests in [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/).  When I make changes to the code or the tests, the console refreshes and the tests appear to re-run, but they don't ACTUALLY re-run.

This is the scenario.

I have 5 tests, they all pass:
[image]

I then add a 6th test to the code, the console refreshes, but the result looks exactly the same (still says 5/5 passed... no indication there is a 6th test).
If I modify the code in a way that one of the previously-passing tests obviously fails.. again, it appears to re-run the tests, but the exact same results show up: 5/5 tests passing.

If I QUIT the test runner and restart it, it will run the new tests and the new code and show the correct results...

I'm unsure why this is or where to look for fixing it.

My `vitest.config.js` looks like this:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.js'],
    globals: true
  },
})
```

my `vite.config.js` looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3002,
    open: '/index.html',
  },
  resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'], // Include both .tsx and .js extensions
    },
})
```

This is with version 5.1.6 of vite and 1.4.0 of vitest